# anchor inside <p> breaks out of <div> with padding applied

Tags: html, css

here is my html file

```
<div>
<p>My text content is here......</p>
<p><a href="#">lINK1</a><a href="#">lINK2</a></p>
</div>
```

and here is the css

```
div {
    width:960px;
    border:1px solid;
    margin:0 auto;
}
a {
    padding:10px 10px 50px 10px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

now what happens is that due to padding top and bottom of my anchors to a total of 60px they actually float out of my main parent division. And I cannot have a fixed height for my div since the length of my content is not fixed. Can anyone suggest how do i decide width of div to enclose  within it??

Comment: @ChrisHardie: I had the same problem. I tried adding `display: block;` but it din't work for me. Check [this](http://www.veershubhranshu.com/resume.php#tags), there I have tried using that. Due to the same problem I am not able to add more tags

Comment: display: inline-block; is what's needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to make the anchors display as `inline-block` like so.

http://jsfiddle.net/J7FTX/

```
div {
    width:960px;
    border:1px solid;
    margin:0 auto;
}
a {
    padding:10px 10px 50px 10px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a {
    padding:10px 10px 50px 10px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

this should fix your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `display: inline-block` to CSS property of your anchor tag and it should start working.

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/sgaurav/2aeBn/